# Tall stalks with berries

Tags: berries

[image]

A friend recently found this in a garden in southern NJ. The stems appear to be 18" tall, the berries about the size of blueberries. What is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pl@ntNet says it is most likely [Arum italicum](https://identify.plantnet.org/the-plant-list/species/Arum%20italicum%20Mill./data). See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arum_italicum.

Looks like the berries aren't ripe yet, and that they will be a nice, bright red when they are.